# R: replace columns of matrix if vector fulfills certain condition

Tags: r

I have a pretty large matrix and I want to delete all columns that have column mean == 1. I have used the following code to accomplish this:

```
an.mdr[,colMeans(an.mdr)==1] <- NULL
```

I get the following error  message:

> NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Could anyone help me out what the problem with this batch of code is? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you explain how it can be done (maybe with small example): *delete all rows that have column mean 1*

Comment: I am sorry. It should read columns instead of rows. I have corrected my mistake in the original post.

Comment: `mdat <- matrix(c(1,NA,1, 1,1,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
               dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"),
                                c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3"))) ;mdat[, colMeans(mdat, na.rm = T)==1,drop=F]`

Comment: @PoGibas OP ask for matrix subsetting, not for a dataframe. And you refer to a dataframe subsetting question.